# python request connectionError

Tags: python, requests

Имеется 25к ссылок, по котором нужно перейти и спарсить данные. Парсер работает в 15 потоков.
К сожалению, я ни как не могу закончить работу, выкидывает ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Danilshik\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 141, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "C:\Users\Danilshik\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 83, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\Danilshik\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 73, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Danilshik\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Danilshik\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 346, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\Danilshik\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 850, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Danilshik\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 284, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Users\Danilshik\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 150, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001D433B9D0B8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Danilshik\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 440, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Users\Danilshik\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 639, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Users\Danilshik\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 388, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='store.steampowered.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /app/790790/Impossible_Runner/?snr=1_7_7_230_150_189 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001D433B9D0B8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Project/parsers/games/steam.py", line 267, in <module>
    start_parse_games()
  File "D:/Project/parsers/games/steam.py", line 252, in start_parse_games
    for _ in executor.map(parse_game, url_games):
  File "C:\Users\Danilshik\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 586, in result_iterator
    yield fs.pop().result()
  File "C:\Users\Danilshik\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 432, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "C:\Users\Danilshik\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 384, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "C:\Users\Danilshik\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 56, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "D:/Project/parsers/games/steam.py", line 115, in parse_game
    r = requests.get(url, cookies = cookies, headers = headers)
  File "C:\Users\Danilshik\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 72, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Danilshik\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Danilshik\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 508, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Danilshik\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 618, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Danilshik\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 508, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='store.steampowered.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /app/790790/Impossible_Runner/?snr=1_7_7_230_150_189 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001D433B9D0B8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера',))
```

Ошибка банальна - меня просто отключает из-за большого количества соединений.
Варианта обхода: поменять IP-адрес,но использование proxy будет очень замедлять программу.

Хочу попробовать отловить эту ошибку и через какое-то время продолжить парсинг.

Но я ни как не могу поймать эту ошибку:

```
def request(url):
    while True:
        try:
            r = requests.get(url)
            if r.status_code != 200:
                log.info("Ошибка, Код ответа: %s", r.status_code)
                time.sleep(1)
                continue
            else:
                return r
        except Exception as e:
            log.info("Ошибка ConnectionError")
            time.sleep(1)
```

Первоначально парсер работал в 20 потоков, подумал что ошибку выкидывает из-за максимального единовременного количества соединений, поэтому снизил до 10, а потом до 5, все равно выдает ошибку

Comment: а где вопрос? в последнем примере у вас бесконечный цикл "пока не выполнится успешно" в нём и ошибка обрабатывается

Comment: в том то и смысл что ошибку он не ловит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests, time, concurrent.futures

def request(url, retry=2):
    try:
        r = requests.get(url)
        assert (r.status_code == 200), ("Ошибка, Код ответа: ", r.status_code, url)
    except Exception as _e:
        if retry:
            print('retry=', retry, url)
            return request(url, retry=(retry - 1))  # retry fail
        else:
            raise  # fail
    else:
        return r  # ok

urls = ['http://error_url_{0}'.format(x) for x in range(3)]  # url с ошибкой - перезапуск
urls.extend(['https://www.google.com', ] * 3)  # url с HTTP 429 Too Many Requests кодом ответа
urls.extend(['https://www.ya.ru', ] * 10)  # и url нормальный

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
    future_to_url = {executor.submit(request, url, retry=2): url for url in urls}
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
        url = future_to_url[future]
        try:
            response = future.result()
        except Exception as exc:
            print('FAIL: %r generated an exception: %s' % (url, exc))
        else:
            print('OK: %r page is %d bytes' % (url, len(response.content)))
```

out:

```
retry= 2 http://error_url_1
retry= 2 http://error_url_0
retry= 2 http://error_url_2
retry= 2 https://www.google.com
retry= 2 https://www.google.com
retry= 2 https://www.google.com
retry= 1 http://error_url_1
retry= 1 http://error_url_0
OK: 'https://www.ya.ru' page is 57591 bytes
OK: 'https://www.ya.ru' page is 57591 bytes
OK: 'https://www.ya.ru' page is 57589 bytes
OK: 'https://www.ya.ru' page is 57591 bytes
retry= 1 http://error_url_2
retry= 1 https://www.google.com
retry= 1 https://www.google.com
retry= 1 https://www.google.com
FAIL: 'http://error_url_1' generated an exception: HTTPConnectionPool(host='error_url_1', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000025D4CF88B50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))
FAIL: 'http://error_url_0' generated an exception: HTTPConnectionPool(host='error_url_0', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000025D4CF9DA60>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))
FAIL: 'http://error_url_2' generated an exception: HTTPConnectionPool(host='error_url_2', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000025D4CFAC580>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))
OK: 'https://www.ya.ru' page is 57655 bytes
OK: 'https://www.ya.ru' page is 57589 bytes
OK: 'https://www.ya.ru' page is 57653 bytes
OK: 'https://www.ya.ru' page is 57653 bytes
OK: 'https://www.ya.ru' page is 57591 bytes
OK: 'https://www.ya.ru' page is 57589 bytes
FAIL: 'https://www.google.com' generated an exception: ('Ошибка, Код ответа: ', 429, 'https://www.google.com')
FAIL: 'https://www.google.com' generated an exception: ('Ошибка, Код ответа: ', 429, 'https://www.google.com')
FAIL: 'https://www.google.com' generated an exception: ('Ошибка, Код ответа: ', 429, 'https://www.google.com')
```

Comment: здесь по сути вы вызываете этот  же метод, например, как высчитывается факториал?

Comment: ошибка все равно вылизиет

Comment: извиняюсь, сам ошибся

Comment: Здесь надо хотя бы какой то ограничитель попыток сделать. А то в бесконечный цикл по ошибке будет уходить, что на мой взгляд - не хорошо. Добавить счётчик пусть 100, 1000 попыток, но должно быть ограничение.